# MySql++ (C++) Segmentation fault under peculiar conditions

Tags: mysql++

check out the following code:

```
#if 1
    mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
    conn.connect(FACE_DB_NAME, "localhost","root", "root"); 
#endif

m_pconn = new mysqlpp::Connection(false);
m_pconn->connect(FACE_DB_NAME, "localhost","root", "root");
```

if "1" is #defined, and the Connection object is on the stack, both chunks of code execute (conn.connect, and m_pconn->connect)

if "0" is #defined, and the second Connection object is dynamically allocated, I get a segmentation fault on m_pconn->connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the original application was compiled using:

_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

mysql++, however, was not.

Will need to look at this more deeply to understand the issue with the CRT, when I get a chance.